# Why wasn't Complete List of Fallacies turned into a wiki?

Tags: discussion

Why not make [Complete list of logical fallacies](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/12728/35858) a Wiki or big list, rather than closing it?

Comment: The comments under the "question" cover this quite well: SE is for single questions with single answers so that a long list does not accomplish anything.